# Design view of Eclipse windowbuilder pugin on Windows 8.1 x64 prompts "Unknown GUI toolkit"

Tags: java, eclipse, windows-8.1, windowbuilder

I was using Eclipse Kepler Release 1 x64, wiht Java 7 x64 on Windows 4 pro x64 and I had no problems with Eclipse WindowBuilder plugin. But since I upgraded to Windows 8.1 pro x64, WindowBuilder has stopped working.

First the follwoing button is freezed and does not respond to user clicks.
[image]

And if in project explorer I go to some java file that I have already created with WindowBuilder plugin in windows 7 x64, right click on it and choose: *Open with > WindowBuilder Editor*, source code opens fine, but when I switch to *Design* view, I get `Unknown GUI toolkit`.
[image]

Stacktrace:

```
org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.utils.exception.DesignerException: 103 (Unknown GUI toolkit). guis.UsersAll
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.prepareParseContext(JavaInfoParser.java:1195)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.parse(JavaInfoParser.java:242)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.access$9(JavaInfoParser.java:238)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser$1.runObject(JavaInfoParser.java:153)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser$1.runObject(JavaInfoParser.java:1)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.utils.execution.ExecutionUtils.runDesignTime(ExecutionUtils.java:159)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.parse(JavaInfoParser.java:151)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.internal_refreshGEF(DesignPage.java:534)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.access$9(DesignPage.java:522)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage$8$1.run(DesignPage.java:449)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:180)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:150)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4688)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage$8.run(DesignPage.java:446)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:464)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:372)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialog.run(ProgressMonitorDialog.java:507)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.internal_refreshGEF_withProgress(DesignPage.java:465)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.internal_refreshGEF(DesignPage.java:415)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.UndoManager.refreshDesignerEditor(UndoManager.java:381)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.UndoManager.activate(UndoManager.java:90)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.handleActiveState_True(DesignPage.java:263)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.handleActiveState(DesignPage.java:241)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.multi.DefaultMultiMode.showPage(DefaultMultiMode.java:125)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.multi.DefaultMultiMode$1.widgetSelected(DefaultMultiMode.java:63)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1081)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1066)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:778)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setSelection(CTabFolder.java:3080)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onMouse(CTabFolder.java:1772)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$1.handleEvent(CTabFolder.java:279)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4170)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:138)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:610)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
```

So can anyone tell me how to get WindowBuilder work on Eclipse on Windows 8.1 pro x64?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't need to reinstall the whole WindowBuilder. Your toolkit was probably SWT, and SWT designer might not come included in your eclipse download. All you need to do is to add SWT designer features to your WindowBuilder from "Install New Software" menu, selecting default Luna installation site, searching for "SWT Designer".

Comment: Or "Swing Designer".

Answer (score 4):

I fixed the problem by:

1. Unistalling the window builder
2. Downloading the zip package of the new version of the window builder from [here](http://eclipse.org/windowbuilder/download.php).
3. Then I extracted that and put its extracted directory inside dropins folder of eclipse.
4. Then restarted eclipse.

And WindowBuilder worked fine.

Comment: I can confirm that, fixed it for me

Comment: Before doing so give this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30776931/2107731) a try.

Comment: had the same problem with eclipse-java-2018-09-win32, and this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was getting the jfxswt.jar file and adding it into my library for that project.

C Drive > Program Files > Java Folder > jdk 1.8 . . .(Version may vary) > jre > lib

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem so I deleted an entire folder of workspace as I was at the initial stage of learning so didn't have many files in the workspace. Then I uninstalled the WindowBuilder plugin and reinstalled it and created
new project-->package-->WindowBuilder-->JFrame and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was to add:

```
requires java.desktop;
```

to my module-info.java, as also suggested in another answer, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56729553/5538923 .

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to eclipse IDE
2. Click project menu
3. project properties
4. Go to java build path
5. chose module path and add library and choose 1.7 version.