# Eclipse Luna (4.4.0): WindowBuilder installed but not appearing to use in "Select Wizard" menu

Tags: eclipse, windowbuilder

I have installed Swing Designer, SWT Designer and WindowBuilder Core exactly as described in [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oeswfZz4IW0).

As I wanted to create new GUI, I could not find the WindowBuilder option in the "Select Wizard" menu (File -> New -> Other...).

[I wanted to post an image of how the Wizard appear to me, but I don't have enough "reputation" or what... I hope I described my problem clearly enough]

I did everything as was done in the video. I have checked twice, that the WB is installed. When I tried to install it again, a warning was displayed that it is already installed. Also, in the folder where the Eclipse files are (`C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.wb.core.lib_1.8.0.r44x201412082350\lib`), there is an evidence of the WB - something is there.

I have tried to update those plug-ins. They are the latest version now, the problem remains nevertheless.

Comment: Are you doing this in a WindowBuilder project?

Answer (score 0):

Adding "-clean" to the eclipse startup arguments did solve this issue for me.
This can be added via the eclipse.ini file

[Screenshot to en eclipse.ini example. I cannot add the image directly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JshST.png)

Problem Description:

- The WindowBuilder did not show after the installation for me as well.
- Installing the WindowBuilder and the SWTDesigner from https://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/latest/ nor from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2019-12 did work. (Both done via Eclipse Software Installer)
- after adding "-clean" the WindowBuilder was correclty displayed

Background:

- Explanation of -clean: https://eclipsesource.com/de/blogs/2013/08/22/eclipse-command-line-options/
- description of launcher init: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini

Answer (score 0):

Time consuming initial steps: The Distribution of the Eclipse Repository resulting from the keyword "WindowBuilder" is incomplete, in my case.

From [Installing WindowBuilder Pro](https://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/download.php) you get the suitable repository URL, e.g.

http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/lastgoodbuild/

providing the complete list of packets.

All well displayed in a tutorial video [How to Install WindowBuilder in Eclipse and Start Designer Window](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l0DvVgqy_q8)

Answer (score -1):

From the information you gave me, it seems like you are not using a WindowBuilder project. To create one, go to your select wizard menu, and select SWT/JFACE project. Then you should be able to use WindowBuilder.

**EDIT**: The tutorial you watched is a little dicey, use this link in the "Install new software" menu: http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/release/R201406251200/4.4/

Select all the options there. It should work after a restart. A good rule of thumb would be to turn your antivirus off, some do not allow programs to execute programs downloaded from the internet.

P.S: Don't use WindowBuilder, code by hand instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see SWT/JFACE project in the menu.
I uploaded the picture [here](http://s28.postimg.org/lxldlgnql/WB_problem.png)
Or is it different wizard menu you are talking about?
I am talking about File -> New -> Other... -as mentioned in the post

Comment: Okay, I reinstalled the WB and all according to what you have suggested. I also tried to download it as a .zip packet and then extract it to eclipse folder (as described in the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24524941/design-view-of-eclipse-windowbuilder-pugin-on-windows-8-1-x64-prompts-unknown-g?rq=1)
I still have the same problem. WindowBuilder seems to be installed, but it can not be used, or its project can not be created. Isn't there a setting "allow extraneous plug-ins" or something like that?
I can reinstall the eclipse, but I doubt it would work.